# Unable to fire event on following image click in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically generating a button containing some text and an image. I want that when I click on button anywhere except image, TASK A should perform, and when I click on image, TASK B should happen. But in my case, only TASK A is happening, even when I click on image.

I am using jquery. This is how the button looks. Inside the button contains a label containing the text and image on the right. [image]

Following code is used for creating button & image
code creating button

```
    newTier1 = document.createElement('button');
    newTier1.className = 'col-md-12 btn btn-light dept-list';
    newTier1.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    newTier1.style.textAlign = 'justify';
    newTier1.innerHTML = '<label>' + tier1list[i].companyDeptName + 
    '</label>';
```

code for creating image

```
    img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = '../images/head.jpg';
    img.className = 'image-responsive direct-search';
    img.style.width = '40px';
    img.style.height = '40px';
    img.style.cssFloat = 'right';

    newTier1.appendChild(img);
```

Event code when button is clicked:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.dept-list', function (e) {
  // TASK A
})
```

For image event click, I have tried 2 things, both did not work:

(1)adding function when generating image

```
img.onclick = function () {
    // TASK B
}
```

in above case, onclick attribute is not there in generated HTML
[image]

(2)jquery

```
$(document).on('click','img.direct-search', function(){
    // TASK B
})
```

Task A happens in both cases, program is not even entering in the second option.

Works fine on chrome. Let me know for any doubts. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```js
newTier1 = document.createElement('button');
newTier1.className = 'col-md-12 btn btn-light dept-list';
newTier1.style.cursor = 'pointer';
newTier1.style.textAlign = 'justify';
newTier1.innerHTML = '<label>companyDeptName</label>';

img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = '../images/head.jpg';
img.className = 'image-responsive direct-search';
img.style.width = '40px';
img.style.height = '40px';
img.style.cssFloat = 'right';

newTier1.appendChild(img);

document.body.appendChild(newTier1)

$(document).on('click', 'button.dept-list', function(e) {
  console.log("TASK A")
})
$(document).on('click', 'img.direct-search', function() {
  console.log("TASK B")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But it is working in chrome. Any work around for IE?

Comment: Add a call to `event.stopPropagation()` in the `img` click handler. Honestly, I'm more surprised this works at all; you really shouldn't change the effect of a `button` element depending on exactly where you click it

Comment: In Chrome I also get TaskB AND Task A when I click the image

Comment: Chrome is fine, there I can use event.stopPropagation() to filter out, but I have to use in IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the question originally.

I solved the issue by simply using

```
<a>
```

instead of

```
<button>
```

This:

```
newTier1 = document.createElement('a');
```

instead of:

```
newTier1 = document.createElement('button');
```

Now it is identifying image inside as a separate element.